# Problems with recognizing variables and methods from same package

Tags: java

I understand how to use and import outside packages, but I've never packaged my own classes before. I read the [Oracle Tutorial on Creating a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html), and looked at [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private/215505#215505) in addition to several sites/SO threads on packages.  For the life of me, I can't figure out why this extraordinary simple example doesn't work:

```
package PTest;

public class A
{
    protected final int SIZE = 10; 

    public void printSize()
    {
        System.out.println(SIZE);
    }
}

package PTest;

public class B
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(SIZE);
        hello();
    }
}
```

I used eclipse's autopackaging feature, so I assume that the actual packing is correct.  Here's an image to show that they are indeed packaged correctly:
[image]

As you can see, neither the `protected SIZE` or the `public hello()` are recognized.  I've tried this outside of eclipse, also to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got so caught up in the idea that it was something wrong with the way that I was using `package` that I completely forgot about main being `static`. This would've been abundantly clear had I gotten an error along the lines of: "can't access SIZE from a static context."  Nonetheless, this is why I shouldn't program when I'm too tired. Sigh.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIZE` is an instance field of `A` objects. You need to make it a static field. Even then, it'll be a member of the `A` class, so you have to specify `A.SIZE` to use it in `B`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I didn't even think about main being `static`.  I feel so stupid, thank you.

Comment: This would've been abundantly clear had I gotten an error along the lines of: "can't access SIZE from a static context." Do you know why this isn't the error?

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage He says "you need to make it a static field."

Comment: @SteveP.: It's because you used `SIZE` instead of `A.SIZE`. The IDE doesn't know you want the field from `A`. If you'd specified `A.SIZE`, you would've gotten an error about accessing a non-static field from a static method.

Comment: @user2357112 That makes sense, I just though by virtue of putting them in the same package that it would know.  Nonetheless, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

[Class methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) cannot access `instance` `variables` or `instance methods` directly—they must use an object reference.

Comment: Thanks I understand.  I just completely forgot that main was `static`.  It's been a long night.  I guess what threw me off was that I didn't get an error along the lines of "can't access xyz from a static context"..

Answer (score 1):

Errors you getting are fixed here

```
package PTest;

public class B
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {  
    A MyClassA = new A();               
    System.out.println(MyClassA.SIZE);
    MyClassA.printSize();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand java, just completely forgot that main was `static`.  For reference, you shouldn't use an identifier that has the same name as your class.

Comment: ty just came back to fix it and saw your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly access methods or fields which are not static (instance members) being in a static scope(main) other than using an object and then access or making those instance members as staic.(class members)

Comment: I think you're being downvoted because you're saying that it's not possible.  Perhaps you should add that they can be found in a `static` context by invoking the classes' name and then using `.`.  Nonetheless, I understood what you meant +1.

Comment: thanks Steve for understanding it correctly. I'll be more descriptive in next time

Comment: Might as well just edit your question, and perhaps the down-voter will remove their downvote.